# Deploy runnable spring boot jar to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, spring-boot

I'm trying to get an executable Spring Boot jar to deploy on Heroku.

I have told Heroku to deploy from a github repository that contains only these files:

```
.
├── Procfile
└── current/
    └── <my application>.jar
```

My `Procfile` looks like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar current/*.jar
```

This is the error I get in the Heroku build log when I try to deploy:

```
-----> Failed to detect app matching no buildpack
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-
failure
 !     Push failed
```

If I look at the `heroku/java` build pack project in github, I can see that there's a script called `detect` that checks for the existence of a `pom.xml` file:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/blob/master/bin/detect

I believe my project isn't being deployed because I don't have a pom in the root directory.

Is it possible to just deploy a project that contains only an executable jar and a Procfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the JVM buildpack instead, which you can do by setting the `heroku/jvm` buildpack on the app instead of the `heroku/java` buildpack.

For example, you can run:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/jvm
```

Or set it in the Heroku Dashboard's Settings tab for the app

Comment: Thanks for that - I actually stumbled across this after I posted my question. Has Heroku changed recently? I'm sure when I tried deploying just a runnable jar in an otherwise empty git repo 6 months ago it worked without any issues...